# What does the following script do?

Tags: bash

What does the following script do?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(ls|grep -E "*\.$1$"|wc -l)
```

Answer (score 8):

Its *intent* is probably to count the number of files in the current directory with a "dot suffix" that matches the one supplied as a parameter to the script. However it seems to have been written by someone who is confused about a few things:

- the use of `*` at the **beginning** of the regular expression `"*\.$1"` doesn't really make sense. In BRE, `*` without any preceding atom is literal, and presumably the writer discovered that adding `-E` makes it a quantifier matching zero or more instances of the empty string. Either way it is superfluous, and the grep may be written as simply `grep "\.$1$"`
- there's no need for `wc` since `grep -c` can count matching lines
- there's no need to capture the output of grep/wc and then use echo to print the thing you just captured.

So you could change it to

```
#!/bin/bash

ls|grep -c "\.$1$"
```

**However grepping the output of `ls` in this way is poor practice.** In particular, Linux filenames may contain newlines, throwing off the count. A better way would be to use filename expansion (aka "globbing") directly e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

files=( *."$1" )
echo ${#files[@]}
```